# Client side Actionscript library charting solution

Tags: charts

Is there any solution for charting for Actionscript? I am willing to pay, does not have to be free.

If there is no actionscript library, what are people using that develop with actionscript? Separate HTML5 application? Is there some embedding option?

Thanks!